# Select Count From Two Tables Without Counting The Columns That Have Repetition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server database. These tables have the same columns, we can say it's a copy - I use one for Archive data and the other for current use of data.

The Archive table doesn't have a primary key because sometimes there can be repetition, and sometimes the primary key may be found in the current table and a copy in Archive table.

I would like a `SELECT` statment to count the number of columns from the two tables without counting repetition of the primary key, because the primary key in the first table may be found two times or more in the second table.

Comment: Using GroupBy using the key will group duplicates together.

Comment: You need to count the number of columns? If there are N records on the second table for a given key, you need to count them as 1 or as N?

Comment: Yes I want to count the numbers of columns from the two tables without use repetation in the second table

Comment: What does "count the numbers of columns" mean? Do you mean the number of *rows*? Otherwise please clarify.

Comment: i mean the count of the columns that have the same Primary Key without repetation

Comment: I still don't understand this. A table consists of records (rows) and columns. You define a primary key for a table that consists of one or more columns and these identify uniquely a row in the table. Counting these columns makes no sense. If a table has a primary key consisting of company code plus employee number, i.e. two columns, then the count is two, what else? This is why I asked if you mean rows instead. (And in my answer I surmised it's rows you want to count. You haven't commented on my answer, though, so I still don't know if I guessed right or not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(B.*) NO_ROWS
FROM 
   (SELECT <ALL COLUMNS IN BOTH TABLES EXCEPT THE ID>
   FROM 
   (SELECT <ALL COLUMNS IN BOTH TABLES EXCEPT THE ID>
      FROM <CURRENT_TABLE>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <ALL COLUMNS IN BOTH TABLES EXCEPT THE ID>
      FROM <ARCHIVE_TABLE>
   ) A
   GROUP <ALL COLUMNS IN BOTH TABLES EXCEPT THE ID>) B;
```

The [grouping](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) on all the columns will eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to **count distinct** primary keys from the **union** of both tables:

```
select count(distinct pk)
from
(
  select pk from table_current
  union all
  select pk from table_archive
) both_tables;
```

Alternatively you can build a distinct union and then just count its records:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select pk from table_current
  union
  select pk from table_archive
) both_tables;
```

Comment: didn't work bro ):  to let you know i have two identical tables,so they have the same definition

Comment: Well, they do work. As mentioned, they count distinct primary keys from the union of two tables. If it's something else you want, then tell us. Your request is still not clear and you put no effort into explaining or illustrating what you are after. Besides "didn't work" just tells us nothing. We don't know whether you got an error, an undesired result, or some other problem with the query.

Comment: i Use this solution but i don't know if will great in the future                                   select (SELECT Count(Distinct PK) from Archive_Table Where Column='Condition' And PK not in (Select PK From Current_Table 
 Where Column='Condition') ) + (Select Count(PK) From Current_Table Where Column='Condition')